# Merge two ranges into one range using query function in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Please refer to my [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iDwzvBCraHcB8bRlRwoxH0ixGkar64lvyGuAn4V-yrE/edit?usp=sharing).

Basically this is for cleaning up form responses. There are two sets of identical questions in two different sections, results in two ranges. I wanted to merge them into one while retaining their order, dynamically.

```
=query({sheet1!A2:F999;sheet1!G2:L999},"select * where Col1 <> ''",0)
```

This is my try which merged the two ranges in sheet1 but it pulled data from range A2:F999 first, then from G2:L999, messing up the order. Is there any other way to merge them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use `if`, in my opinion, as such

`=arrayformula(if(isblank(sheet1!A2:F),sheet1!G2:L,sheet1!A2:F))`

Btw, you don't need to use ranges as `A2:F999`. If you want to say *"until the end of file"* you can omit the row numbers, and simply use it as `A2:F`